# Is it worth killing the drop pods?

Tags: the-bureau-xcom-declassified

Enemies teleport in using the drop pods, so is it worth destroying the drop pods whilst the enemies are spawning?

Will destroying the pod prevent further waves from spawning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, some of the drop pods can spawn multiple waves.  If you destroy the drop pod, it will prevent further waves from spawning.  However keep in mind they have a lot of health and takes quite a bit to destroy.